# How do i useContext with the old react render() function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do i useContext with the old react render() function?

Error:

```
 react-dom.development.js:57 Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Components:

```
import React, { Component, useContext } from 'react'
import { UserContext } from "../../../firebase/user";

export class UserPanel extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // user: useContext(UserContext),
        }
    }

    showUserEmail = () => {
        const user = useContext(UserContext);
        return <h6 className="mt-3 f-14">{"Welcome, " + user.email}</h6>
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="sidebar-user text-center">

                    {this.showUserEmail()}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default UserPanel
```

Comment: you can't use hooks inside class component. For more rules: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: This is the right answer, you can't.

Comment: then how do i get the user email from useContext?

Answer (score 0):

So i just convert my whole function to hooks instead

```
import React, { Component, useContext } from 'react'
// import man from '../../../assets/images/dashboard/man.png'
import { UserContext } from "../../../firebase/user";

const UserPanel = ({ }) => {
    const { currentUser } = useContext(UserContext);
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="sidebar-user text-center">
                {/* <div><img className="img-60 rounded-circle lazyloaded blur-up" src={man} alt="#" /> */}
                {/* </div> */}
                <h6 className="mt-3 f-14">{"Welcome, " + currentUser.email}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserPanel
```